# Amazon FireOS webview doesn't support History.replaceState

Tags: cordova, webview, meteor, kindle-fire

I'm trying to port my existing android/iOS project to amazon fireOS. I can run the hello world app and point my own app to google.com successfully. My app loads fine on android 3/4 but fails with the following error for fireOS:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<History> has no method 'replaceState' at file:///android_asset/www/js/meteor-rider.js:82
```

I have seen that `replaceState` is not available on the default android browser for os versions 3+, although the chromium browser seems to have it. My android version works fine on Samsung Galaxy phones, which don't use the chromium webview.

I'm wondering if anyone knows why this command might be breaking with the fireOS webview, and how I should try debugging this?

For reference, I'm using the following packages:

- meteor
- meteor-rider
- iron router

I'm happy to post any additional code that would be useful.

Thanks

Comment: which version of FireOS (Which Kindle device)? Depending on the generation you have a different Android base

Comment: Kindle Fire HD 7" (model X43Z60)

I've found also that Iron Router is failing with an alert saying "network error URL=file:///<route name>"